# Error while loading Word2Vec model in gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm getting an `AttributeError` while loading the gensim model available at word2vec repository:

```
from gensim import models
w = models.Word2Vec()
w.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
print w["queen"]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8219e36ba1f6> in <module>()
----> 1 w["queen"]

C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.pyc in __getitem__(self, word)
    761 
    762         """
--> 763         return self.syn0[self.vocab[word].index]
    764 
    765 

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'syn0'
```

Is this a known issue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed the problem with:

```
from gensim import models
w = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
print w["queen"]
```

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Word2Vec' has no attribute 'load_word2vec_format'

Answer (score 6):

In order to share word vector querying code between different training algos(Word2Vec, Fastext, WordRank, VarEmbed) the authors have separated storage and querying of word vectors into a separate class KeyedVectors.

Two methods and several attributes in word2vec class have been deprecated.

Methods

- load_word2vec_format
- save_word2vec_format

Attributes

- syn0norm
- syn0
- vocab
- index2word

These have been moved to KeyedVectors class.

After upgrading to this release you might get exceptions about deprecated methods or missing attributes.

To remove the exceptions, you should use

```
KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format (instead ofWord2Vec.load_word2vec_format)
word2vec_model.wv.save_word2vec_format (instead of  word2vec_model.save_word2vec_format)
model.wv.syn0norm instead of  (model.syn0norm)
model.wv.syn0 instead of  (model.syn0)
model.wv.vocab instead of (model.vocab)
model.wv.index2word instead of (model.index2word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, as `models.Word2Vec` has been deprecated, you need to use the `models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format` instead of `models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format` as shown below.

```
from gensim import models
w = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model.bin', binary=True)
```